# Mouse keeps on scrolling automatically after recent update

Tags: 20.04, mouse-scroll

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. After updating today, my mouse started behaving badly. It was difficult to understand what was going on first, but I think I have some idea now. Depending on whether natural scrolling is turned on or off, the mouse wheel keeps on scrolling either in the upwards direction or downwards direction. This has made it impossible to use my computer. For instance, if I press Ctrl in a browser, it starts zooming in (or out depending on natural scroll selection). I cannot code, because it keep son scrolling the text file.

Please help me solve this. It is driving my crazy.